# Scala - Play framework Creation Exception

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm trying to add a new controller to my Play framwork but I'm having this exception

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for service.GithubService was bound.
  while locating service.GithubService
    for the 2nd parameter of controllers.GithubController.<init>(GithubController.scala:12)
  while locating controllers.GithubController
    for the 3rd parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:28)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:139):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)

1 error
```

Here is the `HomeController.scala` file

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc.{BaseController, ControllerComponents}

trait HomeController extends BaseController {
  protected def controllerComponents: ControllerComponents
}
```

Here is the `GithubController.scala` file

```
package controllers

import javax.inject.Inject
import models.GithubRepositoryDTO
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}
import play.api.mvc._
import service._

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class GithubController @Inject()(
                                  val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents,
                                  githubService: GithubService
                                )(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends HomeController {
  def getStarred(): Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
      githubService.getStarredRepositories()

      Future(Ok("test"))
  }
}
```

Here is the `GithubService.scala` file

```
package service

import models.GithubRepositoryDTO

import scala.concurrent.Future

trait GithubService {
  def getStarredRepositories():Future[Seq[GithubRepositoryDTO]]
}
```

Here is the `GithubServiceImpl.scala` file

```
package service

import javax.inject.Inject
import models.GithubRepositoryDTO
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class GithubServiceImpl @Inject()(
                                  wsClient:WSClient
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends GithubService {
  def getStarredRepositories(): Future[Seq[GithubRepositoryDTO]] = {
    //some code
  }
}
```

I've checked if the error comes from the service or controller but still not working, any help or suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `GithubServiceImpl` has not been registered with the dependency injection container. You can find information on how to do this in the [Providing custom bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Providing-custom-bindings) section of the documentation.

The two options are:

1. Using binding annotations:

   ```
   @ImplementedBy(classOf[GithubServiceImpl])
   trait GithubService {
     def getStarredRepositories(): Future[Seq[GithubRepositoryDTO]]
   }
   ```
2. Using programmatic binding, in a file called `Module.scala` in the root of your application:

   ```
   import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
   import com.google.inject.name.Names

   class Module extends AbstractModule {
     override def configure() = {
       bind(classOf[GithubService])
         .to(classOf[GithubServiceImpl])
     }
   }
   ```

Be sure to read the linked documentation for more details on other options and declaring a binding as a singleton.